# Review submitted to the wrong answer

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

While doing some reviewing on Low Quality Posts, I was in this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4816493)

I recommended close, and when prompted for the reason I chose one (sorry don't remember which one) and hit the done button. It seemed to not respond so I hit it again. At that point the review item was replaced by [another review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4816559), without closing the popup window.

The result was that I did two reviews instead of one, and the second one was wrong. I should note here that at no point I pressed "recommend close" to the second review.

So I guess that there is a bug in the way the ajax posts for review fetch the review item's id

Has anybody experienced something similar before?

Comment: Problem with asynchronous code…

Comment: @gnat I don't see how this question is duplicate with the one you mention, they might affect the same page but it is a totally different thing. What I report is: The form (step 2 of close recommendation) where we submit a reason for a close recommendation on an answer/question can apply the desired action-and-reason to more than one answers/questions. The wrongfully reviewed element receives the action reason (step 2) without going to step 1 (hit the recommendation button)